# Images downloaded with cordova file plugin not found by ionic2 app

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am developing an Ionic2 app. I have downloaded a zip file from server using cordova file plugin. Zip is successfully unzipped and I am able to get images and other files(.json) from that directory in Android.

When I view my app on IPAD (ios9.3.5), I can successfully read .json files from the downloaded and unzipped folder, but images are not shown on ipad. When I use safari to debug that. it gives error `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D3AB555E-77B3-48E4-9868-9DFA5C4C8973/Documents/cbsapp/d47kndffqc/questionimages/questionImage0015.jpg Failed to load resource`.

my config.xml has

```
    <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

In the page

```
readonly mainDirectoryName: string = "cbsapp";
  fs: string;        
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                this.fs = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
            }
    this.imagesBaseUrl = this.fs + this.mainDirectoryName + "/" + this.passedId + "/questionimages/";
```

When I see the package in IPAD from XCODE the images are in the package.

I want to know why images are not read my ipad, but it read all other files from same folder.

Everything runs well on android.

Please help.

Comment: How image name:questionImage0015 is getting generated? I think you have trimmed out the important part. When I tried to define source of an image using cordova.file.dataDirectory, it is working fine for me in simulator. Better you inspect the app in simulator first to check what src is getting added and then try in iPad.

Comment: It is working in simulator, but not on actual device. But Now I have solved it. Thanks